# websocket server for django application

Tags: python, django, websocket, socket.io, tornado

I have a django application need to be deployed under Apache HTTP Server, also i need push event to client's web browser at real time.
I'm rather new to python, could anyone suggest some websocket server could work in Python+Django+Apache?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Django is a synchronous web server. it means you cannot use websocket directly with it. But you have various option to do websocket in Django.

**Use a full python stack to do it:** use [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) and Django. You can follow this [post](http://thinkfaster.co/2015/01/run-django-on-tornado)

**Use Nodejs + socket.io + message broker :** Follow this type of [tutorial](http://maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/)

You will find more resources to help you doing that with node.js & socket.io than using tornado.

Comment: the environment i must use is python+django, django could be easily deployed on Tornado? The second option seems more complex?

Comment: The second option add complexity in your web stack: it means that added to python you have to deal with javascript langage. plus you'ill use a message broker (redis). It depends of your need. If you are more confortable with python, go with Tornado. Tornado can run Django server with no problem. See [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/3jFOuYVGlbk).

Comment: Thanks Alex, i will go 1st option for a try now. I know socket.io should perform better than Tornado, is that true? In the future i will also give the second option a try.

Comment: Which option do you suggest to be used in production environment? Stability is most important, performance second.

Comment: Well. The only thing I can tell is that socket.io is really well [supported](http://socket.io/#browser-support) by all browser ;)

Comment: How could i know which browser(version) is supported by Tornado? BTW, my django application need to be deployed under Apache, this should conflict with Tornado?

Comment: I have gone with node+socket.io+redis, it seems work now:) Thanks~

Comment: This answer is out of date. Right now Django Channels are the solution.

Answer (score 2):

With the new update (Django 1.10) Django does now support websockets.

Please read this article for more information: [In deep with Django channels - the future of real time apps in Django](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django)